# sql GROUP BY produces syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't understand what is wrong with this query. It keeps producing a syntax error. Thank you very much.

```
SELECT 
    `employees`.`ID`, `employees`.`LNAME`, `employees`.`FNAME`, `employees`.`MINIT`, 
    `leave_app`.`ID`, `leave_app`.`CONTROL_NUM`, `leave_app`.`DATE_FILED`,
    `leave_app`.`DATE_FROM`, `leave_app`.`DATE_TO`, `leave_app`.`TYPE`, 
    `leave_app`.`EMP_FK`
FROM employees
LEFT JOIN `trackr_pgso`.`leave_app` ON `employees`.`ID` = `leave_app`.`EMP_FK`
ORDER BY `employees`.`ID` ASC
GROUP BY `employees`.`ID`
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I have something like this:

```
1|  6/7/2014
1|  6/30/2014
1|  7/1/2014
2|  6/15/2014
3|  6/29/2014
```

What i want is like this:

```
1|  6/7/2014
    6/30/2014
    7/1/2014
2|  6/15/2014
3|  6/29/2014
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` comes after `GROUP BY`

Comment: Using Group By disregards other records.it only shows 1 record. Pls help. Thank u...

Comment: I'd just like to point out to you that what you are doing here is not very idiomatic SQL and may be accepted as a valid query by MySQL but will fail on other, more rigorous RDBMS (eg. PostgreSQL). The reason is: when grouping, the fields that you have in the `SELECT` clause should either be: a quantity that you are grouping on or an aggregate function of any other quantity. MySQL will accept the query but be aware that you should **NOT** rely on the non-aggregated quantities.

Comment: One last thing: what exactly is the difference between your first and your second example? What date are you _specifically_ interested in retrieving?

Comment: i don't want to repeatedly display the ID.that is all.

Comment: What you display is eventually up to what you do with the query result afterwards. I just don't get why you wouldn't want the ID. Can you explain? Do you want separate rows or are you happy with just one row per ID?

Comment: I will be adding the fullname of the employee later on.And I don't think it's presentable to see same name over and over again. do you have any idea on how can i show only 1 name for many records?

Comment: WELL, of course you could use (ugly) display tricks with ordering and `IF`s (and one subquery) but that's definitely orthogonal to what _relational_ stands for in a result set. Couldn't you rather show, eg., the first date, the last date and the number of individual dates for each employee on a single row?

Comment: Otherwise, if your concern is one of sheer result display, I'd suggest using `GROUP_CONCAT` with a line break separator.

Answer (score 4):

You have to put your `order by` clause after your `group by` clause:

```
SELECT `employees`.`ID` , `employees`.`LNAME` , `employees`.`FNAME` , `employees`.`MINIT` , `leave_app`.`ID` , `leave_app`.`CONTROL_NUM` , `leave_app`.`DATE_FILED` , `leave_app`.`DATE_FROM` , `leave_app`.`DATE_TO` , `leave_app`.`TYPE` , `leave_app`.`EMP_FK`
FROM employees
LEFT JOIN `trackr_pgso`.`leave_app` ON `employees`.`ID` = `leave_app`.`EMP_FK`
GROUP BY `employees`.`ID`
ORDER BY `employees`.`ID` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

You have to `group` first and than you have to `order` .

Here is the syntax from [Mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
    [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
    [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options
      | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
      | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
    [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

Comment: You mean the OP should have checked the manual for their version of MySQL - just like the error message tells them to? Astounding :-)

Comment: Thanks.It did eliminate the error. Please check on my modification. Sorry for the bad format. I am newbie here.. :D

Comment: @user3606736 For my better understanding: What you want is only one times the id?

Comment: Yes, but it should not disregard the column DATE_FILED. Thank you.

Comment: @user3606736 I think it is not possible in mysql.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that, OP should clarify what he/she wants imo because the two examples seem just about the same to me so far.